# Can't make link inside td vertically centered

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

As a homework I'm building a website, I built up this menu using a "table" and put an "a href" inside each "td". The problem is I can't figure out how to make the text written in the "a" inside the "td" vertically centered.
Any ideas?

**CSS:**

```css
.men {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5vw;
    border: 3px white solid;
    border-width: 3px 0px;
    border-color: aliceblue;
}

td{
    width: 25%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 2vw;
}

a{
    color: aliceblue;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

a:hover{
    color: #2f2f2f;
    background-color: aliceblue; 
}
```

```html
<table class="men">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="http://i.imgur.com/zxl58Pv.jpg?1" style="display:block;width:100%;height:100%;text-decoration:none;">MUSEI</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://i.imgur.com/zxl58Pv.jpg?1" style="display:block;width:100%;height:100%;text-decoration:none;">COMPITI</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://i.imgur.com/zxl58Pv.jpg?1" style="display:block;width:100%;height:100%;text-decoration:none;">PAGINE PERSONALI</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://i.imgur.com/zxl58Pv.jpg?1" style="display:block;width:100%;height:100%;text-decoration:none;">CONTATTI</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: They look vertically centered to me in Firefox 36.0.1. What browser are you using?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j7p91ka8/ line-height for a tag added. is it aligned now?

Comment: Chrome 41.0.2272.89 m not working

Comment: No it's not aligned D:

Comment: May it be a broswer problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the inline style `display:block;`, because `vertical-align` only works on an `inline` or `table-cell` box.

Alternatively, you can use equal top and bottom `padding` for the `<a>` like this.

```
td a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1vw 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

And remove all the inline styles from it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3nzkr8kx/1/

Comment: Removed the inline style and put padding: 1vw 0;

Answer (score 0):

I simplified your HTML since you had inline styles that could be handled by a CSS selector. Also, the `display:block` property should be removed to fix the vertical middle alignment.

```css
.men {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5vw;
    border: 3px white solid;
    border-width: 3px 0px;
    border-color: aliceblue;
}

td {
    width: 25%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 2vw;
}

a {
    color: aliceblue;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #2f2f2f;
    background-color: aliceblue; 
}
```

```html
<table class="men">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="http://i.imgur.com/zxl58Pv.jpg?1">MUSEI</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://i.imgur.com/zxl58Pv.jpg?1">COMPITI</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://i.imgur.com/zxl58Pv.jpg?1">PAGINE PERSONALI</a></td>
        <td><a href="http://i.imgur.com/zxl58Pv.jpg?1">CONTATTI</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't add another right answer but your one is working too thanks!

Comment: I resolved removing the inline style and adding a padding to align

Comment: this is not quite what OP needs I think, the hover style isn't quite the same as it is in the question.